# Getting no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, certificate, pfx, chilkat

I need to open, read, and get the path of .pfx file. The file is inside my android studio project folder, MyApp/certificate/mycertificate.pfx.

```
public void openFile(){
    CkCert cert = new CkCert();
    File file = new File("/certificate/mycertificate.pfx");
    String pfxFilename = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String pfxPassword = "1234";
    cert.LoadPfxFile(pfxFilename,pfxPassword)};
```

I'm getting the following error: *No such file or directory*. Any suggestion?

Solved:
I moved the file to \app\src\main\assets

```
public void open(Context context){
InputStream cert= context.getAssets().open("mycert.pfx");
    char[] password = null;
    KeyStore keystore = null;
    Enumeration<String> aliases;
    String alias = "";
    //open the file
    senha = "1234".toCharArray();
    keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(cert, password);
    //Get the alias
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = null;
    PrivateKey pk = null;
    try {
        aliases = keystore.aliases();
        while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliases.nextElement();
            System.out.println(alias);
            if (keystore.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keystore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password));
                pk = pkEntry.getPrivateKey();
            }
        }
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("CATCH", e);
    }
```

}

Comment: `new File("mycertificate.pfx")` does not point anywhere meaningful. Where exactly is this file on the user's device?

Comment: It's not in any device yet. It's only in the root folder of my android studio project. 
MyApp/certificate/mycertificate.pfx.
I tried File file = new File("/certificate/mycertificate.pfx") and still getting the same error.

Comment: But your app is running on your Android device. And you are in town. You are never without phone. How could it find a file on your pc then!?

Comment: running the app in my device wouldn't automatically get all the stuff [classes, libs, files, imgs etc ] it needs?

Answer (score 0):

> It's only in the root folder of my android studio project

That file is on your development machine, not on any device. Instead, package it as an asset (`src/main/assets/` of your module) and use `AssetManager` to `open()` an `InputStream` on that asset.

Comment: Something like this?
InputStream certificate;
certificate = getClass().getResourceAsStream("mycertificate.pfx");

Comment: @Tito: No, something like `getAssets().open("mycertificate.pfx")`. `getAssets()` is a method on `Context`.

Comment: InputStream certificate = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("mycertificate.pfx");

Comment: Now I'm getting W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Tito: Presumably, you are trying to do this from a field initializer. Do not try to use `getApplicationContext()` (which is unnecessary here) or `getAssets()` until after `super.onCreate()` of your activity or service.

Comment: I Solved it!
public void open(Context context){InputStream certificate = context.getAssets().open("mycertificate.pfx")};